# Local AWS serverless application model python application could not able to load jira module

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

Local AWS serverless application model python application could not able to load jira module. It is working fine if i use pycharm run option but whenever i use debug option it throws exception

my requirements.txt is as follows,

```py
cherrypy
dash-table
dash
dash_core_components
dash_html_components
dash_renderer
flask
Jinja2
jira
jupyter-core
markupsafe
nltk
oauthlib[signedtoken]
pandas
pbr
plotly
pymongo
python-dateutil
requests
splunklib
boto3
botocore
sklearn
```

also tried with mentioning jira version like 
jira==2.0.0/jira==1.0.8 etc

whole exception message

```py
START RequestId: 52fdfc07-2182-154f-163f-5f0f9a621d72 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 52fdfc07-2182-154f-163f-5f0f9a621d72
REPORT RequestId: 52fdfc07-2182-154f-163f-5f0f9a621d72  Init Duration: 15853.40 ms  Duration: 0.02 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 133 MB 
{
  "errorType": "Exception",
  "errorMessage": "Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name jira was given, but was not able to be found.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"\u003cfrozen importlib._bootstrap\u003e\", line 696, in _load\n",
    "  File \"\u003cfrozen importlib._bootstrap\u003e\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"\u003cfrozen importlib._bootstrap_external\u003e\", line 728, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"\u003cfrozen importlib._bootstrap\u003e\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 5, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n    import project.helper as helper\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/project/helper.py\", line 15, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n    import project.jira_helper as JiraHandling\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/project/jira_helper.py\", line 6, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n    from qbojira import JiraController\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/qbojira/JiraController.py\", line 2, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n    print (pbr.version.VersionInfo('jira').version_string())\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/pbr/version.py\", line 467, in version_string\n    return self.semantic_version().brief_string()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/pbr/version.py\", line 462, in semantic_version\n    self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/pbr/version.py\", line 449, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources\n    result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/pbr/packaging.py\", line 874, in get_version\n    name=package_name))\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue when I tried to upload my code with packages on AWS lambda function. After much research, trial and errors, adding the idna packages along with the jira packages worked for me.
**idna
idna-2.10.dist-info
jira
jira-2.0.0.dist-info**